# How do I clear a GridPane while keeping the gridlines

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I have used GridPane.getChildren().clear(), however it does not work.

Comment: Please create MCVE https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Note that showing grid lines in a `GridPane` is supposed to be for debugging purposes only (see [documentation](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/layout/GridPane.html#gridLinesVisibleProperty)).

Comment: @Slaw my gridlines have been permanently set to visible but however when i want to clear the labels off my gridpane it clears the gridlines as well.

Comment: why? you are probably barking at the wrong tree: gridpane doesn't support what you seem to want (except for debugging) ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the `gridLinesVisible` property is a debugging feature and should not be relied on for creating a specific look.

That being said it's possible to ensure a rectangular area in the `GridPane` contains lines by adding `RowConstraints`/`ColumnConstraints`. The following code results in lines around a 2 x 2 area:

```
GridPane grid = new GridPane();
ColumnConstraints cconstraints = new ColumnConstraints(10);
RowConstraints rconstraints = new RowConstraints(10);
grid.getColumnConstraints().addAll(cconstraints, cconstraints);
grid.getRowConstraints().addAll(rconstraints, rconstraints);
grid.setGridLinesVisible(true);
```